# Unit Test for JSON to check number of columns

Tags: python, pytest

The JSON file structure looks like:

```
 "name": "zener diode",
 "components": "4-1/2 designed \n1/2 to reliably allow \n1 current to flow "backwards" ",
 "url": "http://https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode",
 "image": "http://https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode.jpg",
 "Thresholdtime": "45M",
 "WaferYield": "8",
 "datePublished": "2010-10-14",
 "downTime": "5M",
 "description": "I have a good, basic wafer "
```

I am trying to create a test which validate columns in JSON always to be in same structure and number as shown above, it has 9 column.

if more than 9 column, than invalid JSON.

Please help me, if it is possible using python or pytest.

Many Thanks

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to `pyspark` which you used as one of tags.

Comment: @Daweo: I am sorry, removed Pyspark Tag, i have mistakenly added, as pipeline was created with Pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check if the length of it:

```
obj = {
"name": "zener diode",
 "components": "4-1/2 designed \n1/2 to reliably allow \n1 current to flow "backwards" ",
 "url": "http://https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode",
 "image": "http://https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode.jpg",
 "Thresholdtime": "45M",
 "WaferYield": "8",
 "datePublished": "2010-10-14",
 "downTime": "5M",
 "description": "I have a good, basic wafer "
}


assert len(obj.keys()) == 9
# true
```

Comment: Checking `len(obj)` will do the job too, and is arguably clearer ;-)

Comment: @dh762: can we check object length opening the JSON file placed in the path. Please suggest

Comment: open the json file, parse it with json.load() (or json.loads()), then check length.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`assert len(my_dict) == 9`

Comment: :can we check object length opening the JSON file placed in the path. Please suggest